# Password reset in cPanel doesn't work while in localhost it working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem of

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

It comes when it want to reset password to my Laravel project

actually on my localhost password reset work property but today I host my project and it doesn't work so help me. I have tried to configure `.env` file well but result remain the same.

Comment: As i understand the request for resetting password instead of `POST` goin as `GET`, and also please give more info, some codes etc.

Comment: Actually the problem caused by clicking on reset password button sir but help me in all possible ways

Comment: it is sending a `GET` request, can you show me the html?

Comment: i have solved it and i appreciate you.